# How do I make this Prolog query work in a predicate?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make this Prolog query:

```
placeRedBlocks(4, X), findall(Y, loopReplace(X, Y), A).
```

which outputs this:

```
A = [[r, r, r, b], [r, r, r, r], [b, r, r, r]],
X = [b, b, b, b]
```

work in the code if I only type in

```
placeRedBlocks(4, X).
```

The code I am using:

```
printList([ ]).
printList([H|T]) :- print(H), nl, printList(T).

placeRedBlocks(Length, List) :-
  findall('b', between(1, Length, _), List).

replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):-
  I > -1,
  NI is I-1,
%  write([H|T]),
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
%  replace(L, _, _, L).

placeRedBlockUnit(A,_,0,_,A):- !.
placeRedBlockUnit(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
  Index1 is Index+1,
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
  placeRedBlockUnit(BLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,NLine).

loopReplace(ListToReplace, NewList) :-
    length(ListToReplace, Len),
    TotalCount is Len-3,
    between(0, TotalCount, Iterations),
    between(3, Len, Size),
    placeRedBlockUnit(ListToReplace, Iterations, Size, 'r', NewList).
```

Unfortunately, if I change `placeRedBlocks` to this it doesn't work.

```
placeRedBlocks(Length, List) :-
  findall('b', between(1, Length, _), List),
  findall(Y, loopReplace(List, Y), _).
```

and I only get:

```
X = [b, b, b, b]
```

What is happening here?
Is it possible for it to return back to the same list?

Comment: You are throwing away the longer list (last parameter of 2nd call to `findall/3`).

Comment: You need three arguments in your predicate:

`placeRedBlocks(Length, List, List2) :-
     findall('b', between(1, Length, _), List),
     findall(Y, loopReplace(List, Y), List2).`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that as long as I use a variable twice in a predicate I don't need to make it a parameter to my predicate.

Changing this

```
placeRedBlocks(Length, List) :-
  findall('b', between(1, Length, _), List)
```

to this

```
placeRedBlocks(Length, List3) :-
  findall('b', between(1, Length, _), List),
  findall(Y, loopReplace(List, Y), List2),
  append([List], List2, List3).
```

made me able to use the queries in the predicate while also keeping the predicate at 2 parameters.